# Why the regex with re.findall() doesn't work?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I tried to extract the text from a html code. And here's my code:

```
import re
Luna = open('D:\Python\Luna.txt','r+')
text=Luna.read()
txt=re.findall('<p>\s+(.*)</p>',text)
print txt
```

However, it only eliminate the part before the first `<p>` and everything after the first `<p>` remained. What should I do to improve my code so that it would only return the part between`<p>`and`</p>` ?
Here's a part of the original html code:

```
src="/advjs/gg728x90.js"></script></td>  </tr></table><div class="text" align="justify"></p><p> Sure. Eye of newt. Tongue of snake.</p><p>  She added, &ldquo;Since you&rsquo;re taking Skills for Living, it&rsquo;ll be good practice.&rdquo;</p><p>  For what? I wondered. Poisoning my family? &ldquo;I have to baby-sit,&rdquo; I said, a little too gleefully.</p>
```

Comment: Obligatory warning about parsing HTML with Regex: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](//stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Answer (score 1):

I *strongly* recommend you use a proper HTML parser, like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(Luna.read())
para_strings = (p.get_text() for p in soup.find_all('p'))
txt = [p.strip() for p in para_strings if p.startswith(' ')]
```

You can fix your regex by using a non-greedy operator (append a `?` question mark to the `*` operator):

```
txt=re.findall('<p>\s+(.*?)</p>',text)
```

However, you'll most likely run into other issues with regex parsing, as HTML is not a regular language.